# How to do timeseries clustering based on shape in python?

Tags: python, time-series

I have tried to cluster time series data based on their shapes in python using hierarchical clustering. But the code seems not so good for my data-set. I have 5 types of shapes and each type have their different 20 types. Now I need to cluster them. 
Can anyone please help me with the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Your question is a little too broad. You'll get better results focusing on one aspect of your problem, creating a [mcve] for it, then asking here - you may end up asking more than one question. Or, craft a question for a suitably narrow part of your algorithm - just make sure you make it clear you are asking about your algorithm.  Sometimes just creating a minimum reproducible example helps you understand your problem better.

Comment: For your [mcve], ensure you include an example dataset either real or *made-up*, if needed for the code.